# Make grid from images

Tags: images, batch-processing, automation, image-processing

I have N images in foldes with the same dimensions (HxW).
Is there any software that can resize all images to the configured size (for example proportionally reduce size of the pic by X) and build a one image - grid of this images? Maybe only build a grid from images without resize?

For example - i have 20 images 900*300, after give the folder with images as input to the software i'll get one image:
3000*200 (2 rows, 10 colums of images 300*100).

Comment: The solutions in [this thread here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19587/method-for-batch-layout-of-images-into-pdf-sheets/19594) might work for you.

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19594/4216) is the way to go.